# getting one result table from two resultset query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

query 1 :

```
select EmpID, count(ProgramId) as "TotalPrograms", 
             SUM(Cast([NoOfDays] as INT) ) as "Total No of Days"  
             from **EmpTrainingInfo**  group by EmpID
```

result output : EmpID  Total Programs ,Total No Of Days

Query 2 :

```
select  AssignedTo [EmpID]  ,count(ProgramId) as "Total Foreign Visits" 
          from **ProgramInfo** where status in ('Completed','Assigned') 
          and Country NOT IN ('Country1','Kountry1 ','cntry1')   group by AssignedTo
```

result output : EmpID, Total Foreign Visits

How can I combine these two to get the Output columns  in one table  :

```
 **EmpID** , **Total Programs** ,**Total No Of Days**,Total Foreign Visits
```

Any tips will be appreciated..

Comment: Which database you are using???

Comment: How the two tables `EmpTrainingInfo` and `ProgramInfo` relate to each other? By which columns?

Comment: EMPID=AssignedTo relates each other

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** Based on your follow up question in comments

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(q1.EmpID, q2.EmpID) EmpID, -- if its a INNER JOIN use just q1.EmpID
       q1.TotalPrograms, 
       q1.TotalNoofDays, 
       q2.TotalForeignVisits, 
       q2.TotalHomeVisits
  FROM
(
    SELECT EmpID, COUNT(ProgramId) AS TotalPrograms, 
           SUM(Cast([NoOfDays] AS INT) ) AS TotalNoofDays
      FROM EmpTrainingInfo
     GROUP BY EmpID
) q1 FULL OUTER JOIN -- it might be just JOIN depending on your data setup
(
    SELECT AssignedTo EmpID, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN Country NOT IN ('Country1','Kountry1 ','cntry1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalForeignVisits,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Country     IN ('Country1','Kountry1 ','cntry1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalHomeVisits
      FROM ProgramInfo
     WHERE status IN ('Completed','Assigned') 
    GROUP BY AssignedTo
) q2 ON q1.EmpID = q2.EmpID
```

Comment: thanks!! but what happen if i have another sql query for one more column like this, SELECT AssignedTo EmpID, count(ProgramId) as TotalHomeVisits
      FROM ProgramInfo
     WHERE status IN ('Completed','Assigned') 
      AND Country  IN ('cntry1','kntry1','kontry1')
    GROUP BY AssignedTo

Comment: @user2139057 You're quite welcome. You don't need a separate query for that. Instead use conditional count in your second query. See updated answer

Comment: @user2139057 Did it help after all?

Answer (score 0):

Since the two tables relate to each other by the tow fields `EmpTrainingInfo.EmpId` = `ProgramInfo.AssignedTo`, then you need to `JOIN` the two tables using these two fields like this :

```
SELECT
  e.EmpID, 
  COUNT(ProgramId)              AS "TotalPrograms",
  SUM(Cast([NoOfDays] as INT) ) AS "Total No of Days" ,
  COUNT(ProgramId)              AS "Total Foreign Visits" 
FROM EmpTrainingInfo   AS e
INNER JOIN ProgramInfo AS p ON e.EmpId = p.AssignedTo
GROUP BY e.EmpID;
```

Comment: can i use this query as stored procedure

Comment: @user2139057, Yes, you can.